# TeamCity - Filter the Change Log to see only changes not yet built

Tags: github, teamcity

We are using TeamCity 2023.05.  I have a project with a number of sub-projects.  All sub-projects are in github, each with a VCS Root being the default branch.

When I click on the project then the Change Log tab we see a wonderful list of all changes across all sub-projects (even including all branches, filterable to see only the default branches).  This alone has improved our process immensely.

But there is one thing in this view that I cannot find that I would have expected.  It is not obvious from this list which changes have not yet been included in a build.  If I click on the commit hash of a change, I can see for that one change whether or not it has been included in a build.

Is there a way to see which changes have not yet been built when looking at the list all changes?  Even better, is there a way to filter the list of changes?